# C++ standard types extension

Tags: c++, types, double

What can I do, if I want add functionality for calculating absolutely/relatively error for double? Can I simply implement MyDouble class, which cover all double functional and may perform this specific operation, and then 'replace' double with this type?

(I want use it like that:

1. Write some code with usually double type
2. Add some header file at the start of my file or write something like `typedef double MyDouble`
3. Estimate errors of double values, accumulating in my code
4. Delete something, that I put in file on point 2)

Comment: Yes... although you'd not exactly "replace" double but rather just use your type instead.

Comment: be more specific on what functionallity you want on a  double

Comment: No, i would like another solution. For example, i have a large code and i want type something like `typedef double MyDouble` for replacing double to MyDouble. I don't want re-write function like sqrt/log/fabs for my new type...

Comment: you can make it convertible to double. What functionallity you actually need on top of a double?

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin and later on you want to change it to for example: `typedef MyDoubleImpl MyDouble`?

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin: I feel like doing something like that would be really fragile and possible break existing code.

Comment: what prevents you to have an external function that calculates it, instead of a method?

Comment: This question, in its current form, is too vague and/or broad.  What are you trying to achieve?  What is "some functionality"?  Why does a solution provoke "No, i would like another solution"?

Comment: People here on SO ask for a lot of information in the comments not because they're annoying or they want to discourage you but rather because often your question is an XY problem, i.e. a problem that can be solved by solving the question "why do you need it?" in the first place

Comment: Yes, my question was very unclear. I try edit it... may be now it's more understandable

Comment: If you are wanting to replace the text `double` with the text `MyDouble` then `typedef` will not do that.  You are probably going to need to use the Preprocessor instead with something like `#define double MyDouble` and create your new type `MyDouble` with the various operations provided by `double`.  Then to remove the `MyDouble` you would just comment out the `define`. You will need to be careful that all places where `double` is used will be able to see the `define` and I am not sure that you would get any warnings if it does not.

Comment: I think about this... but using `#define` very unsafe way and it may broke my(or other) code (for example, with this define, i can't simply use type `long double` because it will be replace to `long Double`)

Comment: This question smells of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You have a solution, and want our help making your solution work, but you don't tell us what the solution you have is intended to actually solve. Please tell us about the actual root problem instead, together with what you have tried to solve it, and we could help you much better.

Comment: What should i explain more detailed in my problem?

Comment: @Nikita, but to estimate error you need really precise calculation. I mean you cannot calculate e.g. exp(1) exactly with computer to compare it to what expl(1) gives you for double. So in theory this task is unsolvable. In practice you can try comparing against long double or re-implement  floating point arithmetic with even longer type, but that seem an overkill to me

Comment: What you can really do (with define as suggested and not with typedef) is to implement MyDouble to watch if double variable becomes denormalized or otherwise close to overflow (and thus is prone to computing errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typedef won't be sufficient to have your own class.  If you need to accumulate errors, overload some operations, or define additional members you'd certainly need a member to hold them,  and also overload operations to define the error propagation rules.

Here is a start:

```
class MyCDouble {
    double d; 
public: 
    MyCDouble(double x) : d(x) {}
    operator double() const { return d; }
    void analyze() {}; 
};
```

You can use such class as if it were a double, thanks to the conversion operator and the constructor.  FOr example:

```
MyCDouble d = 3.14; 
MyCDouble e = sqrt(d); 
e.analyze(); 
cout << "sqrt of "<<d<<" is "<< e<<endl;
e = (d + 5)/3;
```

Now, up to you to add the error management and overload what is needed.  For example, you could add a private member `double error;`, and overload  the operations that propagate errors.  For example, in the class you could add:

```
 MyCDouble operator+ (MyCDouble x) {
     MyCDouble r = d+x; 
     r.error = max(r.error, x.error);  
     return r; 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, i think this is what i looking for)